# Drupal 7 - Creating view of hierarchical content using Taxonomy or content-type

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-taxonomy

I'm trying to create a custom view in Drupal 7 that acts as a landing page for content. I've created a taxonomy group called Expertise Areas which is a hierarchical list of categories - like so:

1. Expertise Area 1

   1. Sub-Area 1
   2. Sub-Area 2
2. Expertise Area 2

   1. Sub-Area 1

Now these terms are used to link relate pages/content types together so for a section of the website called Research Areas, I've got a list of pages - each being a content type of Research Area. Each of these pages defined link to one of the expertise areas listed above (taxonomy term).

The research areas and their expertise area relationships are:

- Research Area 1 (expertise area = 1)

  - Research Sub-Area 1 (expertise area = 2)
  - Research Sub-Area 2 (expertise area = 3)
- Research Area 2 (expertise area = 4)

  - Research Sub-Area 1 (expertise area = 5)

My aim to is create a landing page list of all the Research areas in a hierarchical structure, but I can't seem to work out a good way to do this in Drupal 7. I'm using Views, Token, PathAuto, CCK, etc. This hierarchical structure I'm assuming needs to be based on its taxonomy term relationship as shown in the diagrams above only because I can't work out how to just get a list of nodes of a specific content type in a parent->child format.

I managed to get the Research Area pages in a parent->child structure by moving the links around in the menu admin screens, but there isn't actually a self-referential relationship between the nodes. This is why I thought the only way around it would be to reference the taxonomy group.

Hope this makes sense, really desperate for a solution too. And it's probably an easy one that I am going about the wrong way!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I might not be reading this correctly, but you might want to try using either [Menu Block](http://drupal.org/project/menu_block) possibly in addition to [Taxonomy Menu](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu). Just create a new menu, say Research, and with Taxonomy Menu enabled you can tell the taxonomy to start at that specific menu and then build a list of links based on the terms. With Menu Block, you can then control the menu and place it on a page wherever you'd like, probably on a basic page using context.

Then just style to your hearts content. No Views should be needed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply! I think you're right in the way I've explained it, but what I've realised now is that I didn't mention for each of those quicklinks, I'd like to retrieve data such as a banner image. Therefore, I've created a page for each research area and expertise area and tied to to its relevant taxonomy term.
So essentially, what I'd like to do is retrieve a list of pages in a parent > child structure based on their taxonomy term hierarchy that I can style in a view.